# Разделить строку по точкам, игнорируя контент внутри скобок ()

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Хорошего настроения и продуктивного дня, помогите пожалуйста, нужно разделить строку `str` используя регулярные выражения и не затрагивая то, что находится в скобках.

```
const str = scope.bot.api(https://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=2*(7-3));
// ожидаемый input ['scope', 'bot', 'api(https://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=2*(7-3))' ]
```

Так же выражение не должны ломать скобки внутри скобок как тут - "(7-3)'

Заранее большое спасибо за любую помощь :)

Comment: Приведите однозначные примеры текстов и что в них найти в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let rExp = /(api\(.+\))$|([a-z]+)(?!=[(])/gim;
let sStr = 'scope.bot.api(https://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=2*(7-3))';
console.log(sStr.match(rExp));
```